# 'Failed to create a 'Type' from the text 'local:ImageButton'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a class assembly that contains a number of user controls. I want to add a new type of button to this class assembly and I also want to add styling to it. Specifically I want a button that contains multiple images for use in Normal, Hover (IsMouseOver) and disabled states. It will also contain text to display. Then I could add this in any application using this class assembly as follows:

```
<ns:ImageTextButton NormalImage="{StaticResource SomeImage}" HoverImage="{StaticResource SomeHoverImage}" Text={StaticResource SomeText}" />
```

First I created a C# class:

```
public class ImageTextButton : Button {
   public DependencyProperty ImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Image), typeof(DrawingBrush), typeof(ImageTextButton));
   public DependencyProperty HoverImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(HoverImage), typeof(DrawingBrush), typeof(ImageTextButton));
   public DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(ImageTextButton));

   public DrawingBrush Image {
      get { return GetValue(ImageProperty) as DrawingBrush; }
      set { SetValue(ImageProperty, value); }
   }

   public DrawingBrush HoverImage {
      get { return GetValue(HoverImageProperty) as DrawingBrush; }
      set { SetValue(HoverImageProperty, value); }
   }

   public string Text {
      get { return GetValue(TextProperty) as string; }
      set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
   }
}
```

Then I created a style in a Styles.xaml file which is compiled as a `Resource`.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ImageTextButton}" x:Key="ImageTextButtonStyle">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    CornerRadius="0" Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:ImageTextButton}, Path=Image}">
               <StackPanel>
                  <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:ImageTextButton}, Path=Image}" />
                  <TextBlock Style="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:ImageTextButton}, Path=TextStyle}" 
                             Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:ImageTextButton}, Path=Text}" />
               </StackPanel>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=HoverImage}" TargetName="canvas" />
               </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

I have not been able to test this style and there very well may be issues in it. I can't get the application to start because the `TargetType` above doesn't exist. I believe this is because my Styles.xaml is a resource and the actual class is compiled. The error I get is *Failed to create a 'Type' from the text 'local:ImageTextButton'*.

How can I achieve this? Secondly, is there any way to apply this style by default to this type? I don't want to always have to specify *Style={StaticResource ImageTextButtonStyle}* in each instance of this user item.

Comment: The DependencyProperty fields must be static.

Comment: @Clemens Yes, of course. Thanks for pointing it out. And to whomever downvoted please explain how I can improve my question for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to decide if you are going to build an UserControl or a CustomControl.

UserControl needs to be derived from "UserControl" Base class. As your C# code extends "Button", that implementation doesn't fall under "UserControl".

For a CustomControl, your Style should be present in a file named "Generic.xaml" which SHOULD BE PLACED in a folder "Themes". (You can still change the default Themes Folder location). And your C# file should define the Key which will be used to find/target/identify the Xaml Style.

***Your above setup should not work as it satisfies neither Usercontrol nor Custom Control Requirements.***

I cannot create a full example but can direct you to a certain extent.

You need to have the below Static Method to set your default style as a bare minimum. Add remaining properties as required.

```
public class ImageButton : Button
{
  
    static ImageButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ImageButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ImageButton)));
    }

    public ImageButton()
    {

    }
```

For the Xaml Part. Create a **Folder Themes** and inside that create a resource dictionary by name **"Generic.xaml"**. Inside your Generic.Xaml, add your styles. (Place your xaml logic inside the control template).

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type bc:ImageButton}">
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type bc:ImageButton}">
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

**All the above are bare minimum requirement for a CUSTOM CONTROL**. In case you wish to create a UserControl, you need a .xaml & a .xaml.cs files. You can easily use visual studio context menu (rightclick on solution) and create a usercontrol.

**Important:** *When you are creating a custom control, you dont need something like below*

```
Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:ImageTextButton}, Path=Image}">
```

Just use, TemplateBinding

```
 Background="{TemplateBinding Image}">
```

Comment: Thanks, this gets me further. I have many `UserControl` items already added. This is supposed to be a Custom Control because I want Button behavior and events but simply to template it differently. I never knew there was a standard for the XAML location nor the way to override the style. I had `TemplateBinding` originally but I just get an error `The member Image is not recognized or is not accessible`.

Comment: `TemplateBinding` doesn't work in a `ControlTemplate` Trigger. Hence the binding with RelativeSource. I did get this working. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I have authored an opensource library with several WPF Custom Controls. (The library is regularly updated.)  Please check the github repo. https://github.com/TheHaleyProject/HaleyWPF/tree/development It has 15+ Custom controls (including image button, image combo button, pagination, numeric incrementor among others). I have also published a nuget library Haley.WPF. Check it out and you might get some ideas.

Comment: Crazy - I am making an assembly to add to a bunch of WPF applications. Components I have already added (and are working well) include Paginator, Calendar range, Range slider, and an On-Screen keyboard. Now this button is there. Sounds like I could have saved myself some work in the past.

Answer (score -1):

The RelativeSource Mode *FindAncestor* is missing

change `{RelativeSource AncestorType=local:ImageTextButton}` to `{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:ImageTextButton}`